# alt+tab on Windows 7 remoting to Windows XP

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, remote-desktop, alt-tab

I am remoting into Windows XP, from a Windows 7 client using regular remoting client that comes with Windows.

in the options, it is set to use alt+tab on remote machine in fullscreen mode (which I am in) 
however it keeps using clients alt+tab.

same thing was happening for launchy (alt+space), but I simply quit local launchy, and than it started invoking the one on the remote machine.

what can I do to make alt+tab working on remote machine?

Comment: As [mentioned](http://superuser.com/a/212569/86828) by kzh, ALT-PgUp works and it even works when in windowed mode, so it is a good workaround. Alt-tab _should_ work in full screen mode when enabled in the settings (it works for me), so there might be some bug or quirk preventing it.

Comment: ah, thanks for commenting, but no longer have that setup so can't confirm nor deny if that works in my case :(

Answer (score 0):

I do it the nasty way: I use the on screen keyboard you find in accessories.

You can open it also from start-->execute--> osk.exe

I bet there's an elegant solution but this works :)

Comment: damn.. but is that really better than just using task bar to switch between programs?

Comment: I just use it in awkward and extreme remote controlling situations to send key combinations (not the classic alt+tab, in the end, even if it works):)

Answer (score 0):

Some keyboard shortcuts are listed here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457106.aspx

```
Client         Equivalent     Description
=============  =============  ===========
ALT+TAB        ALT+PAGE UP    Switches between programs from left to right.
ALT+SHIFT+TAB  ALT+PAGE DOWN  Switches between programs from right to left.
ALT+ESC        ALT+INSERT     Cycles through the programs in the order they were started.
CTRL+ESC                      Switches the client between a window and full screen.
CTRL+ESC       ALT+HOME       Displays the Start menu.
ALT+DELETE                    Displays the Windows menu.
PRINT SCREEN   CTRL+ALT+-     Places a snapshot of the active window in the Remote Desktop session on the clipboard.
CTRL+ALT+DEL   CTRL+ALT+END   Displays the Task Manager or Windows Security dialog box. 
ALT+PRNTSCRN   CTRL+ALT+PLUS  Places a snapshot of the entire Remote Desktop session window on the clipboard.
```